# Round decimals in report formula

Tags: crystal-reports, decimal, rounding

My Crystal Report needs to round numbers to two decimal points. I have tried `Round(55.815, 2)` but it returns `55.81` instead of `55.82`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Round(55.815,2) returned 55.82 on my system (Crystal Reports 2008).  What version are you using?  Verify that `Round()` is working as expected: `ToText(Round(55.815,2))`.

Comment: Hi craig,
I need to do this via formula, because I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
The formula is this:

Round({@amount} * {Rows.Tax} / 100, 2);

thks

Comment: hi, I tried to test but does not change... I have an amount of 558.15 and a rate of 10%.... so, I have to find the percentage so:
Round(558.15 * 10 / 100, 2) but it returns 55.81... why? can you help me? thank a lot

Comment: Your `{@amount}` formula may not have the exact value of 558.15 like you think it does and may itself be displaying as rounded. To test, replace `{@amount}` with the exact value of 558.15 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi Ryan... In fact... I solved.. thks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this

`if Remainder(55.815 ,1) > 0.5 then
Floor (55.815) + Remainder(55.815 ,1)
else
Floor (55.815 )+ Remainder(55.815 ,1)`

This may be help you

Answer (score 4):

If you need to round the decimal for display purposes, simply use the "Decrease Decimals" icon:

[image]