# Crystal Reports: Decimal parameter field showed as integer on the footer section

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, decimal, subreport

I have an issue with showing a decimal value on the footer section. Actually, I'm using a parameter field to show a certain statistic on the footer section of a sub-report. When I place it on the details section the decimals show correctly.
Is there anyone who faced the same problem?

```
Example:
10 250,00 instead of 10 250,74: in the details section the correct value is shown.
```

Comment: Is it simply a case of needing to format the field in the footer to show decimal places?  Did you right-click the field in the footer, select Format Field, select the Number tab, then Customise?

Comment: I customized it, but the strange thing is that the field is showing correctly if I put it in the details section.

Comment: That's Crystal Reports for you -- sometimes it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports doesn't work well with number parameters, I always found it easier to convert it to a double by adding a formula `CDbl ({?Parameter})` and use the formula in the report, however this is using the crystal designer **not manipulating via code**.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [round decimal in formula CR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462307/round-decimal-in-formula-cr/15462717#15462717).  Increase the decimal places instead of decreasing them.